# Ruby 1.9.1-p243 - Building a gem using a gemspec that gets updated in run-time

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm building a rake task that pulls down a repo, runs some specs and builds a gem if they all pass.

The gemspec file comes with the original checkout of the repo, and I'd like to bump the version whenever the gem is built (i.e. when the task is run). Gem::Specification.load doesn't let me manipulate the attributes of the gemspec since it just returns nil. The only way I've figured out to do this so far is to create a temp gemspec, replace the version line with what I want and mv it over the current gemspec.

However, the file is not updated until (I think) the process exits. The path and file are nominally there, but there is no content in the file itself, it's just blank. When testing in irb, the gemspec's content appears after exiting the session.

Here's the rake task for gem building:

```
desc "Build new vulnerability tests gem"
task :build_gem do
  Process.fork { update_gemspec_version 'foo.gemspec' }

  gemspec = Gem::Specification.load('foo.gemspec')
  builder = Gem::Builder.new(gemspec)
  puts "Building gem from #{gemspec.file_name}"
  builder.build
end
```

(You can see I thought forking the process to run the method would fix the problem, but it just used the original gemspec to build the gem and didn't update anything until the rake task completed.)

And the update_gemspec_version helper method:

```
def update_gemspec_version(gemspec)
  temp_file = Tempfile.new "#{gemspec}"
  time = Time.now
  minor_rev = 0
  base = time.year.to_s + '.' + time.month.to_s + '.' + time.day.to_s 

  File.open("#{gemspec}", 'r') do |file|
    file.each do |line|
      if line =~ /^\s*s\.version\s=\s'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.(\d+))'$/
        if $1 >= base + '.' + minor_rev.to_s
          while minor_rev <= $2.to_i
            minor_rev += 1
          end
          replacement = line.gsub($1, base + '.' + minor_rev.to_s)
          puts replacement
          temp_file.puts replacement
        else
          replacement = line.gsub($1, base + '.' + minor_rev.to_s)
          puts replacement
          temp_file.puts replacement
        end
      else
        temp_file.puts line
      end
    end
  end
  FileUtils.mv(temp_file.path, File.expand_path("#{gemspec}"))
  nil
end
```

Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gem::Specification.load doesn't let me manipulate the attributes of
>   the gemspec since it just returns nil.

Are you using the latest RubyGems? Gem::Specification.load returns an instance of Gem::Specification if it evaluates the gem spec file successfully... maybe a typo? See https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/specification.rb

Comment: Well what do you know... Previously when I had tested that out in irb, it returned nil, but it definitely doesn't now, and I've edited it successfully. I guess I should have seen it was working in the helper method. Anyway, thanks a bunch. Should make things much cleaner.